# A proper way for PHP worker infinity loop on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, worker

i'm not sure about worker on heroku, my code is proper or not?

my code on github is

```
1-proc file
worker: php run.php

2-run.php file
while(1){
   runthis();
}
```

Comment: php is not really designed for this.